# TemplateHaskell not installed... then it is

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm writing a program in Haskell, and it involves a lot of parentheses. So to clear up that ugly mess, I use the `$` operator a couple of times to make it easier to read. For example:

```hs
longFunc arg1 (anotherFunc (yetAnotherFunc arg2))
```

is replaced by

```hs
longFunc arg1 $ anotherFunc $ yetAnotherFunc arg2
```

But when I compile my program using GHCi I get a message saying:

```
MyFile.hs:18:18: error:
    parse error on input ‘$’
    Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Here's lines 16-18:

```hs
isDigit :: Char -> Bool
isDigit c =
  c `elem` $ ['0'..'9'] ++ "."
```

I was confused because I have used the `$` operator several times (with the same compiler) like this:

```hs
main = putStrLn $ show 42
```

So I typed that code into my file as a test, deleted the other `$` occurrences, and loaded it up.

And it worked!

Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Comment: Please tell us what line 18 is when it generates the error.

Comment: Line 18 is pretty much the same thing as my example with the functions that are called with `$` instead of parentheses

Comment: But the error is on line 18, and not somewhere else. _Something_ is clearly different about that line. There are places where `($)` is not allowed, or may not do what you expect, e.g. on the left of an assignment.

Comment: There, I added lines 16-18 in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `($)` immediately after another infix operator. Line 18:

```
c `elem` $ ['0'..'9'] ++ "."
```

needs to be rewritten as one of the following options:

1. Keep the parentheses as original:

   ```
   c `elem` (['0'..'9'] ++ "."])
   ```
2. Apply `($)` to a slice of `elem`:

   ```
   (c `elem`) $ ['0'..'9'] ++ "."
   ```
3. Convert the call to `elem` to a prefix call:

   ```
   elem c $ ['0'..'9'] ++ "."
   ```

I recommend option 3. Consecutive infix operators (in this case `` `elem` `` and `$`) do not have a well-defined priority and confuse the parser. The general rule of thumb is that an infix operator must always have a complete expression on each side. `` c `elem` `` is not a complete expression, so it is not allowed on the left of `$`. Similarly, `$ ['0'..'9'] ++ "."` is not a complete expression, so it is not allowed to be the right side of `` `elem` ``.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped!